# Stability of discrete-time dynamical systems using Lyapunov stability where A is function of optimization variable

Tags: control-theory, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions, discrete-time

Hi I am trying to solve a constrained optimization problem using the Lyapunov stability. In the problem we aim to find $\beta$ such that

$$\min_\beta ||\beta^TF-y|| \quad \text{s.t.}\quad  A^{T}PA-P<0$$ for some $P>0$ where $P$ is symmetric. These conditions ensure that $A$ is stable which is  required in our application.

From my understanding, this constraint is a Linear Matrix Inequality (LMI) which is convex. However, as in my problem A is also function of the optimization problem $\beta$ the problem is non convex and cannot be solved using semi-definite programming (SDP).
In particular, the first row of $A$ consists of the vector $\beta$ and the following rows are the identity matrix (shifted) such that $y_{t+1}=Ay_t$ where $y_t=[y(t-1), y(t-2),...,y(t-L)]^T$ and $\beta=[\beta_1,\beta_2,...,\beta_L]$ such that
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
\beta_1 & \beta_2 & \beta_3 & \cdots & \beta_{L-1} & \beta_{L}\\
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $$
Are there any ideas on how to solve for $\beta$. Many thanks!

Comment: Please add all the necessary details.

Comment: Hi @KBS thanks for the response! Have added some further details which I think are helfpul. Let me know if this is sufficient now! Thanks

Comment: Have you already tried applying [Schur's complement](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2747010/76466)?

Comment: Hi @KwinvanderVeen, my understanding is that you can only use Schur's complement if  the matrices involved are fixed or only linearly dependent on the optimization variable, however in my problem A depends on β in a potentially nonlinear way.

Comment: Please add the dimensions of the vectors and matrices, it would help understand the problem. If the dimension of $\beta \in \mathbb R^n$ is not too large, you could use robust optimization to constraint $\beta$ to some subspace from $\mathbb R^n$. Then, in the optimization problem you search for a matrix $P$ leading to stability for all $\beta$ in that subspace. When you have a $P$, you take that as fixed and minimize w.r.t. $\beta$. For that to be an SDP, you will need to take $\beta_1$ as constant.

Comment: Hi @Trb2 thanks for the reply! The dimensions are not too large so in theory we can use robust optimization. Could you advise me how to proceed with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem that is directly convex but you can easily derive an algorithm that can find a locally optimal solution.

First note that the problem can be reformulated as

$$
\begin{array}{ll}\min_{P\succ0,\beta\in\mathbb{R}^n} \gamma \quad \text{s.t.}\quad&
(A_0+B\beta^T)^{T}P(A_0+B\beta^T)-P\prec0,\\
& ||F^T\beta-y||\le\gamma.
\end{array}
$$
where $A_0$ and $B$ are obvious from the definition of $A$. This problem is equivalent in turn to

$$
\begin{array}{ll}\min_{P\succ0,\beta\in\mathbb{R}^n}\gamma \quad \text{s.t.}\quad&
\begin{bmatrix}
-P & (A_0+B\beta^T)^{T}P\\
P(A_0+B\beta^T) & -P
\end{bmatrix}\prec0,\\
&\begin{bmatrix}
-\gamma & (F^T\beta-y)^T\\
F^T\beta-y & -\gamma I
\end{bmatrix}\preceq0.
\end{array}
$$

For a fixed $\beta$, the above problem is an LMI problem in $P,\gamma$. Conversely, for a fixed $P$, the above problem is an LMI problem in $\beta,\gamma$. We will exploit this in our algorithm.

Now, we can easily find $\beta$ such that $A+B\beta^T$ is Schur stable because $A$ is in companion form and $\beta$ will contain the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial, which can be chosen to be Schur stable. Alternatively, $\beta$ can be computed by solving an LMI problem.

Now this $\beta$ will serve as an initialization point for our algorithm that reads as follows:

1. Given $\beta$, solve the above LMI problem for $P\succ0$ and $\gamma>0$. Store $P$.
2. Given $P$ solve the above LMI problem for $\beta$ and $\gamma>0$. Store $\beta$.
3. Evaluate a stopping condition (e.g. $\gamma$ does not change anymore). If it is satisfied, then stop the algorithm and return $(\gamma,P,\beta)$ otherwise go to Step 1.

This algorithm is not guaranteed to converge globally, but $\gamma$ is guaranteed to be nonincreasing. So, the sequence of the computed $\gamma$'s will converge.

If needed, several initial conditions can be considered to explore the initialization space and increase the chances of getting a global optimum.

Comment: Hi @KBS thank you for your reply it has been very useful! I've been trying to implement this using CVXPY and I have two questions if you can help:                                                       1. Can we use the identity matrix for P as the starting point?                                          2. When we fix one of the variables should we include both constraints in the LMI problem or just the corresponding constraint for each? Thank you!

Comment: 1. You do not need to consider an initial point for $P$. You will find your first value for $P$ by solving for it at step 1. 

2. You only need to consider the constraints in which the considered variable is involved. So, both inequalities for $\beta$ and only the first one for $P$.